# PHP Socket Program hangs

Tags: php, sockets

I have a socket server program written in PHP and run by Fedora 21-apache, listening on a port.

```
<?php

set_time_limit (0);

$address = '1.2.3.4';

$port = "19000";
$con = 1;
$word = "";

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$bind = socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");

socket_listen($sock);
while ($con == 1)
{
    $client = socket_accept($sock);
    $input = socket_read($client, 50);

    if ($input == 'exit')
    {
        $close = socket_close($sock);
        $con = 0;
    }
    else {
        $input = trim($input) . "," . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
        $file= "/home/xyz/data/" . "uls_" . date("Ymd_His") . ".dat";
        file_put_contents($file, $input);
    }

}

?>
```

The client is actually a device. Currently there is only one device running.
As per the documentation provided by the device,
"It acts as a TCP client and opens a TCP socket session to the Server. The
device then sends a message and disconnects the socket session. Failed connections force retries"

Now I am able to get data from this client. The problem is that after say 4-5 Hours client is not able to push data.The server socket hangs.
The netstat -taun command shows following.

tcp        0      0 1.2.3.4:19000     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

tcp        0      0 1.2.3.4:19000     3.4.5.6:20721       ESTABLISHED

Sometimes more than one client connections could be seen.

I can confirm that the client is still running during this time. I tried to connect to this server socket through another client socket script.
The result says, client request made but server socket did not respond.

If restart the web server, and run the server script again, everyrthing works normal for sometime.

Could anyone help me identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran with the same probleme, i fixed it by closing the **resource** built by `socket_accept()`

```
while ($con == 1)
{
    $client = socket_accept($sock);
    $input = socket_read($client, 50);

    if ($input == 'exit')
    {
        $close = socket_close($sock);
        $con = 0;
    }
    else {
        $input = trim($input) . "," . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
        $file= "/home/xyz/data/" . "uls_" . date("Ymd_His") . ".dat";
        file_put_contents($file, $input);
    }

     // @param2 - 1 => block writing in socket ...
     socket_shutdown ($client , 1) ;
     socket_close    ($client )    ;
}
```

Comment: But according to php  socket_shutdown documentation, the first argument is 'A valid socket resource created with socket_create()'. So will the line    socket_shutdown ($client , 1) has any affect ?. I tried your code with socket_close and without socket_shutdown. Didn't work.